# Imageview gets set multiple time using AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android

I followed the procedure [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) and set up an easy AsyncTask Image downloader/loader for me. I call the download function from inside my GetView of the Adapter. Thus, everytime I scroll up or down, once the view goes out of screen, the images vanish only to be set again when I scroll back to that item. How do I stop this and, once I've all the images downloaded/cached, to set it. I don't want my ImageViews to be reset every single time.

This is the ImageManager:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class ImageManager { 
      private HashMap<String, Bitmap> imageMap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>(); 
      private File cacheDir;
      public Thread imageLoaderThread = new Thread() ;
      public ImageQueue imageQueue  = new ImageQueue();
      public ImageManager(Context context) {
        // Make background thread low priority, to avoid affecting UI performance
         imageLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        // Find the dir to save cached images
        String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
          File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();    
          cacheDir = new File(sdDir,"data/codehenge");
        }
        else
          cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

        if(!cacheDir.exists())
          cacheDir.mkdirs();
      }


      private void queueImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
          // This ImageView might have been used for other images, so we clear 
          // the queue of old tasks before starting.
          imageQueue.Clean(imageView);
          ImageRef p=new ImageRef(url, imageView);

          synchronized(imageQueue.imageRefs) {
            imageQueue.imageRefs.push(p);
            imageQueue.imageRefs.notifyAll();
          }

          // Start thread if it's not started yet
          if(imageLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            imageLoaderThread.start();
        }




    private class ImageRef {
          public String url;
          public ImageView imageView;

          public ImageRef(String u, ImageView i) {
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
          }
        }

    private class ImageQueue {
          private Stack<ImageRef> imageRefs = new Stack<ImageRef>();

          //removes all instances of this ImageView
          public void Clean(ImageView view) {
            for(int i = 0 ;i < imageRefs.size();) {
              if(imageRefs.get(i).imageView == view)
                imageRefs.remove(i);
              else ++i;
            }
          }
    }

    private class ImageQueueManager implements Runnable {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              while(true) {
                // Thread waits until there are images in the 
                // queue to be retrieved
                if(imageQueue.imageRefs.size() == 0) {
                  synchronized(imageQueue.imageRefs) {
                    imageQueue.imageRefs.wait();
                  }
                }

                // When we have images to be loaded
                if(imageQueue.imageRefs.size() != 0) {
                  ImageRef imageToLoad;

                  synchronized(imageQueue.imageRefs) {
                    imageToLoad = imageQueue.imageRefs.pop();
                  }

                  Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(imageToLoad.url);
                  imageMap.put(imageToLoad.url, bmp);
                  Object tag = imageToLoad.imageView.getTag();

                  // Make sure we have the right view - thread safety defender
                  if(tag != null && ((String)tag).equals(imageToLoad.url)) {
                    BitmapDisplayer bmpDisplayer = 
                      new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, imageToLoad.imageView);

                    Activity a = 
                      (Activity)imageToLoad.imageView.getContext();

                    a.runOnUiThread(bmpDisplayer);
                  }
                }

                if(Thread.interrupted())
                  break;
              }


            }
             catch (InterruptedException e) {}
          }



private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
      String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
      File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);

      // Is the bitmap in our cache?
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
      if(bitmap != null) return bitmap;

      // Nope, have to download it
      try {
        bitmap = 
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream());
        // save bitmap to cache for later
        writeFile(bitmap, f);

        return bitmap;
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
    }

    private void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {
      FileOutputStream out = null;

      try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally { 
        try { if (out != null ) out.close(); }
        catch(Exception ex) {} 
      }
    }
}

    public void displayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {


        if(imageMap.containsKey(url)) {

            Bitmap bitmapToShow = imageMap.get(url);

            if(bitmapToShow != null) {
            //> Image was cached well
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapToShow);
            return;
            }
            }

            //> Image was cached failed
        else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_radio);
            queueImage(url,imageView);
            return;
            }



        }

    private class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
          Bitmap bitmap;
          ImageView imageView;

          public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i) {
            bitmap=b;
            imageView=i;
          }

          public void run() {
            if(bitmap != null)
              imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
              imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.spinner_background);
          }
        }


}
```

My View:

```
if( v == null){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    holder.displayPic = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.DisplayPicture);
    v.setTag(holder);

    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        obj = objs.get(position);
        if (obj != null)
        {
            holder.name.setText(obj.Name);
            holder.text.setText(""+obj.snippet);
            holder.displayPic.setTag(obj.ImageUrl);
            imageManager.displayImage(obj.ImageUrl, activity, holder.displayPic);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

getView method is called each time views need to be diplayed, and as this method of downloading images download image for each view, so it loads view with new image every time, to avoid this you would need to implement some type of caching, to implement caching you can have a hashmap or arraylist which may have Bitmaps, but it might result in OutOfMemory as list size invreases, so you can implement caching in filesystem, please follow sample to implement caching:

http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/